# Error: One or more parameter values were invalid--DynamoDb

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to update a table in DynamoDb with the following code..

```
$response = $client->updateItem(array(
    "TableName" => "PlayerInfo",
    "Key" => array(
        "PlayerId" => array('N' => '201503261435580358849074082'),
    ),
    "AttributeUpdates" => array(
        'PlayerPrice' => array(
            'N' => '5'
        ),
    ),
    "ReturnValues" => \Aws\DynamoDb\Enum\ReturnValue::ALL_NEW
));

print_r($response);
```

However, an error interrupts its execution. It says:

```
One or more parameter values were invalid: Only DELETE action is allowed 
when no attribute value is specified.
```

Could anybody help me with this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like the for format of the request was missing the 'Action' and 'Value' parameters. E.g. the following is working for me:

```
$response = $client->updateItem(array(
    "TableName" => "PlayerInfo",
    "Key" => array(
        "PlayerId" => array('N' => '201503261435580358849074082'),
    ),
    "ReturnValues" => \Aws\DynamoDb\Enum\ReturnValue::ALL_NEW,

    "AttributeUpdates" => array(
        'PlayerPrice' => array(
            'Action' => \Aws\DynamoDb\Enum\AttributeAction::PUT,
            'Value' => array('N' => '5'),
        )
    )
));
print_r($response);
```

You can also use an [UpdateExpression](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.Modifying.html) to achieve the same effect (UpdateExpressions also provide greater flexibility than AttributeUpdates so they are generally recommended):

```
$response = $client->updateItem(array(
    "TableName" => "PlayerInfo",
    "Key" => array(
        "PlayerId" => array('N' => '201503261435580358849074082'),
    ),
    "ReturnValues" => \Aws\DynamoDb\Enum\ReturnValue::ALL_NEW,

    "UpdateExpression" => "SET #pp = :val",
    "ExpressionAttributeNames" => array(
        "#pp" => "PlayerPrice",
    ),
    "ExpressionAttributeValues" => array(
        ':val' => array('N' => '5')
    )
));
print_r($response);
```

Comment: Nice answer. Its worth noting that AttributeUpdates has been deprecated now so UpdateExpression is definitely the way to go. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateItem.html#DDB-UpdateItem-request-AttributeUpdates